# Reusing Text views and Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, textblock

I am working on windows phone 8 app.

I am dynamically creating multiple Textview and Grid inside For loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++)
                    {

                        Image image = new Image();
                        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/sample256.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


                        image.Tag = i.ToString();

                        Grid questionGrid = new Grid();
                        questionGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        questionGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

                        TextBlock question = new TextBlock();
                        question.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                        question.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                        question.Text = " this is the question and its id is Question" + i;
                        question.FontSize = 30;
                        question.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        question.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        questionGrid.Children.Add(question);

                        Grid answerGrid = new Grid();
                        answerGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        answerGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

                        TextBlock answer = new TextBlock();
                        answer.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                        answer.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                        answer.Text = "this is answer and its id is Answer" + i;
                        answer.FontSize = 30;
                        answer.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        answer.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        answerGrid.Children.Add(answer);


                        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image);
                        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(questionGrid);
                        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(answerGrid);

                    }
```

As you can see that i have around 300 times its entering, so because of that the load is heavy and there is a lot of delay when page responds to user interaction.

How to reduce the load? so that i can resue the dyamically created views.

Comment: why not use ListBox? and bind items in the listBox

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah no i have to dynamically add due to some constraints, but how to solve this  ?

Comment: If you manage to use LisBox than the loading delay issue will be fixed as Virtualization is applied on the ListBox

Comment: Well, you can create a collection of Images/Views/Grids, will be something like: List<Image> usedImages. Then you can work with this list. But why do you need 300 views? Maybe there's simpler solution.

Comment: You can also create a user control, which has an image and a bunch of textblocks, or/and whatever you like. Then you can add this user control to you page as a single object. I think, that'd be better.

Comment: @Olter but how to bind data to it ?

Comment: I've written an answer, but I still don't understand, why you're using so many objects. 300 is too much, the app will hang. What those 300 views will represent? Perhaps you should think about of partial visibility of your views (Are all 300 always visible? I could hardly imagine that).

Comment: See here http://andreasvilela.com/blog/2013/04/05/windows-phone-xaml-create-carousel-3d-with-images/#comment-58541

Comment: That's definitely a partial visibility, only 5 views are in usage. So, you don't need to create all 300 at runtime, just create 5 of them, and them change the image uris for them, when touching next/previous button.

Comment: @Olter he is loadng all the itesm in one Shot, and what ever you are telling can you please guide  me on that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55695/discussion-between-user2056563-and-olter).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, instead of creating complicated objects directly at page cs code you should create a user control. On you user control you preset the positions for you element, i.e. if you want it to have an Image and a couple of textblocks, you just place them there. That would be a template.

Then, you create list of user controls in a loop.

So, your code would look like:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++)
{
    SomeUserControl someUserControl = new SomeUserControl(constuctorValue1, constuctorValue2);
    ListOfSomeUserControls.Add(someUserControl);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(someUserControl);
}
```

Where ListOfSomeUserControls is a List defined on your page code.

Here, you can send some data to constructor, for example someUserControl will be your ImageUri or text value.

OR, you can create some properties at user control to set data there.

OR, you can create some methods at user control, like ChangeImageUri() or something like that.

To use this dynamically created user controls you should use ListOfSomeUserControls[Index]. You could also save this list somewhere for former usage.

That's the basic idea.

---

In the link, you've shared, the OP creates a list of *links* to images. Feel, the difference: he has 5 Image boxes at the page and a list of 300 links. So, when you start your app you have this:

Image1::listOfUris[1] Image2::listOfUris[2] Image3::listOfUris[3] Image4::listOfUris[4] Image5::listOfUris[5]

When you tap **next** button, you just displace this list by 1.

Image1::listOfUris[2] Image2::listOfUris[3] Image3::listOfUris[4] Image4::listOfUris[5] Image5::listOfUris[6]

That's all, just 5 images, not 300.